# Get element from JSON.parse

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I got a JSON string in my javascript and i would like to access the values.

```
16
    Object { 3488={...}}

3488
    Object { article_no_internal=

"999184"

, article_name_internal=

"Geschenkbox Kerzenschein 2011"

}

article_name_internal


"Geschenkbox Kerzenschein 2011"


article_no_internal


"999184"
```

Here is an images cause the code looks a bit wired... [Parsed json](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/197/asdmh.png)

i tryied something like this: `obj.16.3488.article_name_internal[]` but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: If you parse it correctly to variable `obj`, `obj.16.3488.article_name_internal` should work.

Comment: i get this error: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]  

`alert(obj.16.3488.article_name_internal);`

Comment: @sQVe I think `obj.16.3488` will throw "Unexpected number"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
obj[16][3488]["article_name_internal"];
// or
obj[16][3488].article_name_internal;
```

Comment: works thank you, my train is leaving , i accept your question home.